# How to generate entity classes from yaml files in doctrine 2

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

I am following this link to generate entities from yaml files.

[Doctrine 2 ORM 2 documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/tools.html#tools)

I have installed doctrine2 using composer, using following command on CMD

> D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16>php.exe "D:\jsingh7 stuff\PHP\composer.phar"
>   install

Below is the directory structure that the composer has made in my

> D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\vendor

[image: Doctrine folder structure]

I have very less knowledge about command prompt so facing issue in understanding that why the command in not working.

the command I am using is

C:\Users\jsingh7>php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-entities --help

it shows - Could not open input file: vendor/bin/doctrine

[image: CMD result]

Any guidance will be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshots it looks like you are trying to find and run a doctrine script located in `C:\Users\jsingh7\vendor\bin` when it is actually installed in `D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\vendor\bin`.

Try:

```
C:\Users\jsingh7> php D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\vendor\bin\doctrine orm:generate-entities --help
```

Or perhaps better yet, install doctrine locally for your project (e.g. "myproject"):

1. Create a C:\Users\jsingh7\myproject\composer.json with the following contents:

   `{
       "require": {
           "doctrine/orm": "*"
       }
   }`
2. Run the "composer install" command:

   `C:\Users\jsingh7\myproject> composer install`
3. You should now be able to run the doctrine script locally:

   `C:\Users\jsingh7\myproject> php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-entities --help`